# I started a new Kotlin Android Project but I got this error - "Expected a single classpath entry, found: []"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using the latest version of android studio, with Kotlin. Anyone with a solution will really appreciated

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkRm1.png

Comment: Do not post code as image, use the code-block syntax, three backticks

Comment: Did you get a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are missing, something like that

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 0):

None of those work for you?

If you have ever changed where android is stored (i.e. saving gradle or APK files on an external drive) this may help.

```
Expected a single classpath entry, found: []
```

I had this error but my real problem was very different. Before I upgraded my storage, I used an external drive to host Android APKs and gradle files.

I had promptly forgotten this earlier when beginning a new project, no longer using the external drive!

I went into File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> emptied the "Gradle User Home" so it points back at default.

Fixed! Maybe this will help someone... another example of an error that really didn't reflect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your project is still using the previous project gradle. Open Android Studio, go to File ->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle user home: and select the correct gradle folder (the one which is reside in your current project folder).

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and this solution work for me after trying many other ways.
I went into File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> claer the "Gradle User Home"  at top and save changes.
After that i have updated my Gradle version from 6.5 to 6.7.1 and sync project.
It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me deleting **gradle** **caches** worked.

I am using macos, my user was `joanne`.

So the path to gradle cache was

`/Users/joanne/.gradle/caches`

I deleted everything inside that folder, the error went away