# How do I create a single classpath entry

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Whenever I start my project I am met with the message "Expected a single classpath entry, found: []" and I don't know how to solve it. Any help would be much appreciated

Looking deeper into the error messages it appears to be something with the gradle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146207/i-started-a-new-kotlin-android-project-but-i-got-this-error-expected-a-single

Comment: How would I translate this to Java?